# How can I delete some data from DB in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I'm creating some queries for DB to delete all the test data after performance testing but nothing has happened. The result listener writes that the query was successful.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJQFm.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. You're having 42 errors in your test plan execution, in particular this one:

   > JDBC data source already defined for: delete

   [image]

indicates that you have at least 2 JDBC Connection Configuration (if not 3) which create [connection pools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) for the database so it looks like you created a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) yourself.

Please remove the extra JDBC Connection Configuration elements which define the `delete` pool and it should fix your issue.

2. JMeter listeners obey [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) so it's sufficient to have only one at the same level as Thread Groups, it will "catch" all the sample results from all the samplers
3. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so it worth considering migrating to Groovy, [it has much better performance comparing to Beanshell and numerous extra features on top of normal Java SDK](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black).